# How to build a custom AngleSharp element and insert/transform HTML sections into the element

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, anglesharp

I am using AngleSharp and would like to know how to transform sections of HTML to something like SVG, XML or another custom bracket supported format.

Question: **how do I build a custom AngleSharp IElement and then transform the div (or link) contents inside the custom element** i.e. take the div/links I found, and then put the div content inside in the custom element

---

Below is the code I am trying

```
var divToTransform = document.QuerySelector("div.class1.class2");
// need a custom transform, something simple like replacing the tags
new IElement myCustomeAngleBracketQml = new CustomeAngleBracketQml(divToTransform);
//something simple like replacing the tags
myCustomeAngleBracketQml.Replace("div", Tag).With("QmlDiv");
//insert the content
myCustomeAngleBracketQml.TextContent = divToTransform.innerContent();
//1) how to put this back in the place of the original div, after deleting that div?
///2) *how to target a specific node in the Dom
document./*after Div with class, or Div with Id*/.AppendChild(element);
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

use Xml Linq XElement

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XElement doc = new XElement("QmlDiv", new object[] {
                new XElement("class1", new object[] {
                    new XElement("class2",divToTransform.innerContent)
                }),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, while this is great , I a using [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/) lib (BTW - will your code snippet swap out the div tags with my custom tag)

Comment: Yes, you can add my code to a loop of use linq to enumerate.